Regarding introduction to Symplectic Geometry
I want to learn Symplectic Geometry . Could you please share with me a pathway how to start Symplectic Geometry ? Could you please share some text books and also some good lecture notes ?

It would be useful if we knew your background. In my experience,  Cannas da Silva's notes: Lecture on Symplectic Geometry are a nice introduction to the topic. However, my favorite introductory book is Introduction to Symplectic Topology by Dusa McDuff. It not only contains all the "basics" in symplectic topology, but also provides an overview of the field including very interesting open questions.
I would also recommend to read about J-holomorphic curves, a crucial tool in Symplectic topology.
